# Bootstrap breaking point on nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started using bootstrap recently so I am still learning. My problem is on the navigation bar i have created. I have all the contents pulling right but the search bar and tabs are breaking line. I have tried a few things like setting break points to xs and so on.

here is what it looks like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7xRj.png)

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
         </div>
                        <div class="row-xs pull-right" >
          <div class="col-xs">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
             </ul>
          </div>
                            <div class"col-xs">
                             <form class="navbar-form " role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
             </form>
                                      
                      </div>
                            
                            
        </div>
     </nav>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're HTML is missing numerous elements `row-xs`, `col-xs`, and `row-fluid`  are not classes in Bootstrap3 and you have some syntax errors also.

I would suggest starting out with a standard [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) class and customizing it from there but if you have or want to use columns and row see the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) on the right way to use these in general.

See working examples of a `navbar` and a variation of your code in the Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem and glad I could help.

Comment: If if you have the time could you explain the parts below

Comment: If you reduce the browser viewport to under 768px you'll see a button on the right side on the navbar, this is the toggle button that will now open and close the collapsed navbar panel. The navbar links go from being displayed inline across the navbar to being "hidden" once you're under 768px and this button is what opens (expands) / closes (contracts) the menu.

Comment: Oh okay that's really cool thanks again. You have thought me allot.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
```

and what does "navbar-toggle collapsed" do.
Thanks